# how to fix "Duplicate extensions not allowed" with logstash/jruby?

Tags: jruby, logstash

I'm running logstash like it saids in the starting page:

```
java -jar logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar agent --config logstash-dev.conf
```

With logstash-dev.conf like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/tmp/catalina.jsonevent.log"]
    codec => json {
      charset => "UTF-8"
    }
  }
}


output {
# Use stdout in debug mode again to see what logstash makes of the event.
  stdout {
    debug => true
  }
  elasticsearch_http {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

And it jumps with this error:

```
Exception in thread "LogStash::Runner" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StoreError) loading file failed: problem creating X509 Aux certificate: java.io.IOException: problem parsing cert: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed
    at org.jruby.ext.openssl.X509Store.add_file(org/jruby/ext/openssl/X509Store.java:151)
    at RUBY.initialize(file:/usr/local/bin/logstash/logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar!/ftw/agent.rb:70)
    at RUBY.register(file:/usr/local/bin/logstash/logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar!/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_http.rb:46)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617)
    at RUBY.outputworker(file:/usr/local/bin/logstash/logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar!/logstash/pipeline.rb:208)
    at RUBY.start_outputs(file:/usr/local/bin/logstash/logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar!/logstash/pipeline.rb:140)
```

I've looking everywhere (google, mail groups of logstash and jruby, and the same with their ircs) but I don't find a way to solve this. I only see similar stacktraces but no solution.

Can you give me any pointer in address this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

We've been looking for this as well and this fixed it for us:

```
curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: It had stopped working after upgrading mac to yosemite. This fixed it yet again...