# Java OPC-UA Stack Client java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed

Tags: java, client, opc-ua

im trying to run one of the examples coming with the OPC-UA Java Stack and getting the following Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.opcfoundation.ua.common.RuntimeServiceResultException: org.opcfoundation.ua.common.ServiceResultException: Bad_CertificateInvalid (code=0x80120000, description="2148663296, java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed")
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.TransportChannelSettings.getServerCertificate(TransportChannelSettings.java:114)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.tcp.io.TcpConnection.initialize(TcpConnection.java:376)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.tcp.io.SecureChannelTcp.initialize(SecureChannelTcp.java:273)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.tcp.io.SecureChannelTcp.initialize(SecureChannelTcp.java:246)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSecureChannel(Client.java:640)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSecureChannel(Client.java:555)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSessionChannel(Client.java:370)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSessionChannel(Client.java:345)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.examples.SampleClient.main(SampleClient.java:109)
Caused by: org.opcfoundation.ua.common.ServiceResultException: Bad_CertificateInvalid (code=0x80120000, description="2148663296, java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed")
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.Cert.<init>(Cert.java:143)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.TransportChannelSettings.getServerCertificate(TransportChannelSettings.java:112)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.utils.CertificateUtils.decodeX509Certificate(CertificateUtils.java:193)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.security.Cert.<init>(Cert.java:136)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate extensions not allowed
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.parseExtension(CertificateExtensions.java:115)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.init(CertificateExtensions.java:88)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateExtensions.<init>(CertificateExtensions.java:78)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:702)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
    ... 15 more
```

I tried running another client (c#) and it works.

Comment: Are you using MacOS? See https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl/issues/56, especially https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062548

Comment: Or also related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189648/converting-a-pfx-certificate-to-a-jks-gives-duplicate-extensions-not-allowed-e

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325573/how-to-fix-duplicate-extensions-not-allowed-with-logstash-jruby

Comment: yes i am running on a mac thank you i will look into your links

Comment: sry, im a bit confused i didn't bump into this certificate jungle before do i need to add those mentioned certificates to my keychain ? there a certificates named XXX.per and XXX.pem is this the problem ?

Comment: Can anyone share a solution to this one. Having similar problem on OSX (the same app with the same cert was fine on Windows). Thank you.